# spring + hibernate error while building

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss

```
 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/tims-1.0]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/config/spring/HibernateSessionFactory.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464) [spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111) [spring-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_33]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2277) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2273) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:863) [spring-orm-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:782) [spring-orm-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188) [spring-orm-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) [spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
        ... 20 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider]
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:192) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:114) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:54) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider cannot be cast to org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider
        at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:189) [hibernate-core-4.1.5.SP1.jar:4.1.5.SP1]
        ... 41 more
```

Comment: can any one help me with this error...

Comment: show us your spring-hibernate configuration. What versions or hibernate and spring are you using?

Comment: i am using spring 3.1.1 and hibernate 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Spring classes from the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3` package with Hibernate 4.

Use classes from the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4` package only.